# Webauthn - Windows Hello authenticatorSelection is not working

Tags: node.js, webauthn, password-less

I am just developing a sample node js application to play around webauthn on Windows 10.

```
        challenge: challenge,
        rp: {
            name: "Example CORP",
            id  : "localhost"
        },
        user: {
            id: new Uint8Array(16),
            name: "jdoe@example.com",
            displayName: "John Doe"
        },
        pubKeyCredParams: [
            {
            type: "public-key",
            alg: -7
            }
        ],authenticatorSelection: {
            authenticatorAttachment: "platform" //cross-platform is working fine
        },
        timeout: 60000
        };
        const credential = navigator.credentials.create({
            publicKey: publicKey 
        });
```

I do get back the following error and I am not seeing any modal window of Windows Hello.

```
login:32 publicKey.authenticatorSelection.userVerification was not set to any value in Web Authentication navigator.credentials.create() call. This defaults to 'preferred', which is probably not what you want. If in doubt, set to 'discouraged'. See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/content/browser/webauth/uv_preferred.md for details
```

Are there any additional params I am missing ?

--
Siva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't define `userVerification` property in the `authenticatorSelection` object.

from the [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/):

> Let `userVerification` be the effective user verification requirement for the assertion:

> is set to **required**
> Let `userVerification` be true.

> is set to **discouraged**
> Let `userVerification` be false.

> is set to **preferred**
> If the authenticator
> is capable of user verification
> Let `userVerification` be true.
> if the authenticator not capable of user verification
> Let `userVerification` be false.

```
authenticatorSelection: {
  authenticatorAttachment: "platform",
  userVerification: "required" 
},
```